# IBAN checker error

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python and I am doing it as an extra thing for school. 
My teacher asked us to make an IBAN-generator, but I can't figure out what I did wrong (probably many things) but can anyone help with this one?

my code:

```
letter_dic = {"A": 10, "B": 11, "C": 12, "D": 13, "E": 14, "F": 15, "G": 16, "H": 17, "I": 18, "J": 19, "K": 20,
          "L": 21, "M": 22, "N": 23, "O": 24, "P": 25, "Q": 26, "R": 27, "S": 28, "T": 29, "U": 30, "V": 31,
          "W": 32, "X": 33, "Y": 34, "Z": 35}

def move_digits_to_back(iban_string):
    x = iban_string[0:4]
    y = iban_string[4:]
    iban_string = y + x
    return iban_string

def convert_characters_to_digits(iban_back):
    iban_num = (iban_string)[4:][:4].translate(letter_dic)
    print iban_num
    return int(iban_num)

def is_modulo_correct(iban_num):
    if iban_num % 97 != 1:
        return True
    return False

def validate_iban(iban_string):
    move_digits_to_back(iban_string)
    convert_characters_to_digits(iban_string)
    if is_modulo_correct(iban_num) is True:
        print("IBAN-nummer {} is correct".format(iban_string))
    else:
        print("IBAN-Nummer {} is niet correct".format(iban_string))

while True:
    iban_string = raw_input("Vul een IBAN-nummer in om te controleren.\n")
    validate_iban(iban_string)
```

And the Error

```
    line 13, in convert_characters_to_digits
    iban_num = (iban_string)[4:][:4].translate(letter_dic)
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `iban_string` at that line? Print it beforehand

Comment: Iban string is the iban code but then with the first 4 digits at the back,
for example: NL20ingb0000123445 becomes ingb0000123445NL20

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you can only use `translate` for one-to-one mappings, and in your case you have a letter mapping to two numbers. Here is a version of your code that fixes that. Also, you forgot to get the returned value of `convert_characters_to_string`. Here is a version of your code that solves those problems:

```
letter_dic = {"A": 10, "B": 11, "C": 12, "D": 13, "E": 14, "F": 15, "G": 16, "H": 17, "I": 18, "J": 19, "K": 20,
          "L": 21, "M": 22, "N": 23, "O": 24, "P": 25, "Q": 26, "R": 27, "S": 28, "T": 29, "U": 30, "V": 31,
          "W": 32, "X": 33, "Y": 34, "Z": 35}

def move_digits_to_back(iban_string):
    x = iban_string[0:4]
    y = iban_string[4:]
    iban_string = y + x
    return iban_string

def convert_characters_to_digits(iban_back):
    iban_num = (iban_string)[4:][:4]
    iban_num = iban_num.upper()
    for k, v in letter_dic.items():
        iban_num = iban_num.replace(k, str(v))
    return int(iban_num)

def is_modulo_correct(iban_num):
    if iban_num % 97 != 1:
        return True
    return False

def validate_iban(iban_string):
    move_digits_to_back(iban_string)
    iban_num = convert_characters_to_digits(iban_string)
    if is_modulo_correct(iban_num) is True:
        print("IBAN-nummer {} is correct".format(iban_string))
    else:
        print("IBAN-Nummer {} is niet correct".format(iban_string))

while True:
    iban_string = raw_input("Vul een IBAN-nummer in om te controleren.\n")
    validate_iban(iban_string)
```